# Mvvmcross - GetOrCreateCellFor of TableViewsource is never called

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am trying to set binding between my viewmodel and tableviewsource. But method GetOrCreateCellFor in tableviewsource is never called.

Here is my code:

ViewController:

```
public partial class MainView : MvxViewController
{

    public MainView() : base("MainView", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var source = new TableViewDataSource(FloorTableView);
        this.CreateBinding(source).To((MainViewModel vm) => vm.Floors).Apply();

        FloorTableView.Source = source;
        FloorTableView.ReloadData();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : MvxViewModel
{

    DataService DataService;
    ObservableCollection<Category> _Floors = new ObservableCollection<Category>();

    public ObservableCollection<Category> Floors
    {
        get
        {
            LoadFloors();
            return _Floors;
        }
        set
        {
            _Floors = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Floors);
        }
    }

    void LoadFloors()
    {
        _Floors.Add(new Category { 
            Name = "Test"
        });

    }

}
```

TableViewSource:

```
public class TableViewDataSource : MvxTableViewSource
{

    private static string CellId = "FloorCell";

    public TableViewDataSource(UITableView tableView) : base(tableView)
    {
        tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(FloorCell.Nib, CellId);
    }


    public override System.nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return 50;
    }


    protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        //this method never called
        return tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellId, indexPath);
    }
}
```

FloorCell is simple empty tableview cell which extends MvxTableViewCell.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You *need* to implement the `RowsInSection` method otherwise the method won't get called.

You also need to make sure that the `UITableView` actually has a `Frame` set up either one you set yourself or through auto layout constraints. If the height or width is 0 the method won't get called either.

Answer (score 1):

This might also happen if height of your table view is lower than at least on item including footer / header size. So be sure you calculate height appropriately (with one item available it will add scrolling to your table view, but GetOrCreateCell will be called).